# When we Build WAR through Jenkins , it is unable to load the "application.properties" file . WAR built manually is able to load the properties file

Tags: java, spring-boot, jenkins, war

I am facing a strange issue when I build the jar through Jenkins .
The WAR file created through Jenkins is unable to load the "Application.properties" file . 
Meaning it is unable to inject anything in the "applicationProperties" field in the  "ISellGenevaCacheClient.java" file  - LINE 4

- This issue is only happening when I build the WAR though Jenkins .
- If I build the WAR normally in Eclipse (by maven clean install) , it is able to inject value into "ApplicationProperties" in "ISellGenevaCacheClient.java" file .
- My "Application.properties" file is present under src/main/resources
- Below are the java files being used .

My ApplicationProperties.java

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(locations   ="classpath:application.properties", ignoreUnknownFields = false , prefix="prop")
public class ApplicationProperties {

private String algorithm;

public String getAlgorithm() {
    return algorithm;
}
void setAlgorithm(String algorithm) {
    this.algorithm = algorithm;
}   
}
```

EncryptionUtilitiesImpl.java

```
public class EncryptionUtilitiesImpl {

private ApplicationProperties applicationProperties;

public EncryptionUtilitiesImpl(ApplicationProperties appProp) {    //   Constructor
    applicationProperties = appProp;        
}

public String decryptString(final String cipherTextHex) {
    byte[] key = formEncryptionKeyArray(applicationProperties.getKeyProp());     //  --->  Line 75 :  Here , we are getting the applicationProperties as NULL
    String decryptString = decryptStringFromHexWithMac(cipherTextHex,  key);   
    return decryptString;
}
}
```

Utility.java

```
public class Utility {
public String decryptValue(String encryptedValue){
    EncryptionUtilitiesImpl encryptionUtil = new EncryptionUtilitiesImpl(applicationProperties);
    return encryptionUtil.decryptString(encryptedValue);     //  --->  Line 199
}
}
```

CacheClient.java

```
public class CacheClient  {
@Inject
ApplicationProperties applicationProperties;   //. --->.  LINE 4

@Inject
Utility utility;    
public void init(){
    // -- Some code  .. . . .. 
    Utility.decryptValue(applicationProperties.getAlgorithm()))     // --->   Line 66
    // --- Some code ... . . .
}}
```

I am getting the below NULL Pointer Exception because it is unable to inject any runtime object to 'applicationProperties' field in the "CacheClient.java"  file -- LINE 4 .

Below is the Stack Trace :

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'CacheServiceImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'genevaInstance': Error creating bean with name 'ISellGenevaCacheClient': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'CacheClient': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'CacheClient': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at com.test.util.EncryptionUtilitiesImpl.decryptString(EncryptionUtilitiesImpl.java:75)
at com.test.util.Utility.decryptValue(Utility.java:199)
at      com.test.salesinterface.service.integration.geneva.cache.CacheClient.init(CacheClient.java:66)
```

I am really stuck here . Please Help .

Comment: If you are running it locally from a shell/cmd and not from Eclipse, does it work?

Comment: I created the WAR from Eclipse , and then placed it in the application/ folder of the Extracted tar file . Basically replace the existing WAR file in the application/ folder . If we put the WAR file we built from Jenkins it is throwing this Error.   I am running this from the Terminal (shell) .

Comment: Have you tried to run the `mvn clean install` from the command prompt by giving the project work location?? Eclipse know your classpath so that property file is automatically getting picked but when you are running from the command prompt it should the same error. Please try to run on the command prompt and check.